# How to take user inputs, add it to list objects, then display message for 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm a self-taught beginner.

What I aim to do is better explained in animated gif as seen high-speed below:

[image]

Here are some additional guidelines:

- The form should appear when clicking on the button "Add link".
- If the entered URL does not begin with "http: //" or "https: //", it adds "http: //" at the beginning.
- When the user validates the new link, it is added in top of the page, the add form disappears and an information message is displayed for 2 seconds.

Here are codes I've tried so far:

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <h1>Activity</h1>
    <div id="alert"></div>
    <div id="jax">
      <button id="addLink" onclick="sendTheAJAX()" class="button">Add link</button>
    </div>

    <div id="content"></div>

    <script src="../js/weblinks.js"></script>
</body>
```

**weblinks.js**

```
var linkList = [
    {
        title: "Kottke",
        url: "http://kottke.org",
        author: "brett.suggs"
    },
    {
        title: "National Geographic",
        url: "http://www.nationalgeographic.com",
        author: "jessica"
    },
    {
        title: "American Museum of Natural History",
        url: "http://www.amnh.org",
        author: "aurora.nicole"
    }
];

function createLinkElement(link) {
    var linktitle = document.createElement("a");
    linktitle.href = link.url;
    linktitle.style.color = "#428bca";
    linktitle.style.textDecoration = "none";
    linktitle.style.marginRight = "5px";
    linktitle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(link.title));

    var linkUrl = document.createElement("span");
    linkUrl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(link.url));

    var titleLine = document.createElement("h4");
    titleLine.style.margin = "0px";
    titleLine.appendChild(linktitle);
    titleLine.appendChild(linkUrl);

    var detailsLine = document.createElement("span");
    detailsLine.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Added by " + link.author));

    var linkDiv = document.createElement("div");
    linkDiv.classList.add("link");
    linkDiv.appendChild(titleLine);
    linkDiv.appendChild(detailsLine);

    return linkDiv;
}

var content = document.getElementById("content");
linkList.forEach(function (link) {
    var linkElement = createLinkElement(link);
    content.appendChild(linkElement);
});

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'addLink.html');
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
        document.getElementById('jax').innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
};

function sendTheAJAX() {
    request.send();
    document.getElementById('addLink').style.display = 'none';
}

function checkURL (abc) {
  var string = abc.value;
  if (!~string.indexOf("http://")) {
    string = "http://" + string;
  }
  abc.value = string;
  return abc
}

function onSubmit() {
  var title = document.getElementById("linkTitle").value;
  linkList.push({
    "title": title,
    "url": document.getElementById("xLink").value,
    "author": document.getElementById("name").value
  });
  linkList.forEach(function (link) {
      var linkElement = createLinkElement(link);
      content.appendChild(linkElement);
  });
  var alert = document.getElementById("alert");
  alert.innerHTML = "<p>The link to \"" + title + "\"was succesfully added</p>";
  setTimeout(function () {
    alert.innerHTML = "";
  }, 2000);
}
```

**addLink.html**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
  <input type="text" name="linkTitle" id="linkTitle" placeholder="Link Title">
  <input type="url" name="xLink" id="xLink" onblur="checkURL(this)" placeholder="Link URL">
  <button type="submit" id="add" onclick="onSubmit()" class="button">Add</button>
</form>
```

My questions are:
1) In the checkURL function section, I've tried to add "https://" by:

```
if (!~string.indexOf("http://"|"https://")) {
    string = "http://" + string;
  }
```

It doesn't work. Just make it worse.

2) How to add user input from the form in addLink.html into linkList in js?

3) How to display information message "The link was successfully added" for 2 seconds?

Note: I didn't built code from scratch, the base code was provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `"http://"|"https://"` evaluates in JS to `0`. Maybe you misunderstood logical OR (`||`) with bitwise OR (`|`)? Nevertheless, `indexOf` seems a bit cumberstone here, I would suggest using [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) instead and rewrite `checkURL` as :

```js
function checkURL (str) {
     if (str.value && !/^https?\:\/\//i.test(str.value)) {
         str.value = "http://" + str.value;
     }
}
```

2. Actually you are adding user input from the form into linkList, but since you using button `type="submit"`, you are submitting form on every click and causing page reload. Instead use `type="button"` in your **addLink.html**:

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
   <input type="text" name="linkTitle" id="linkTitle" placeholder="Link Title" />
   <input type="url" name="xLink" id="xLink" onblur="checkURL(this)" placeholder="Link URL" />
   <button type="button" id="add" onclick="onSubmit()" class="button">Add</button>
</form>
```

or `return false` in `onSubmit` function or use [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) at the top of it.

3. Now message should be showing fine, but at the same time you appending existing list with itself again. Either you should add only last element or clear `content` element and 'rerender' the whole list:

```js
function onSubmit() {
  var title = document.getElementById("linkTitle").value;
  linkList.push({
    "title": title,
    "url": document.getElementById("xLink").value,
    "author": document.getElementById("name").value
  });
  content.innerHTML = ""; // clearing the content div
  linkList.forEach(function (link) {
      content.appendChild(createLinkElement(link));
  });
  var alert = document.getElementById("alert"); // can be taken outside the function, as it is engough to get it once
  alert.innerHTML = "<p>The link to \"" + title + "\"was succesfully added</p>";
  setTimeout(function () {
    alert.innerHTML = "";
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Now it works! Definitely, this is the best answer. Although I find it difficult to understand the regex syntax, I just copy paste it and it works. And the "button" instead of "submit" is an enlightenment. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with checking if the URL has the http or https protocol specified. See the snippet below, it uses a regex to check if the provided string starts with either `http://` or `https://`. When neither protocol is specified it will prefix `http://` to the string.

```js
function checkURL (abc) {
  var string = abc.value,
      protocolRegex = /^https?:\/\//i;
  if (protocolRegex.test(string)) {
    return;
  }
  
  abc.value =  `http://${string}`;
}

var
  entries = [
    {value: 'http://stackoverflow.com'},
    {value: 'https://stackoverflow.com'},
    {value: 'stackoverflow.com'}
  ]
  
entries.forEach(entry => {
  checkURL(entry);
  console.log(entry.value);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try a regular expression in the indexOf function call - such as:

```
if (!~string.indexOf(/(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)/i)) {
  string = "http://" + string;
}
```

I don't think you need to escape the colon, but my memory lapses here.

Comment: Will not work as indexOf doesn't accept regex as an argument

Comment: Correct - should have typed out as string.search(regex) - thank you.